# Cumulative sum in a period of months

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, running-totals

I have this table:

| month_rep | fruits | harvested |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 | 139 | 139 |
| 2021-10-01 | 143 | 11 |
| 2021-11-01 | 152 | 14 |
| 2021-12-01 | 112 | 9 |
| 2022-01-01 | 133 | 10 |
| 2022-02-01 | 145 | 12 |
| 2022-03-01 | 123 | 5 |
| 2022-04-01 | 111 | 4 |
| 2022-05-01 | 164 | 9 |
| 2022-06-01 | 135 | 12 |
| 2022-07-01 | 124 | 14 |
| 2022-08-01 | 144 | 18 |
| 2022-09-01 | 111 | 111 |
| 2022-10-01 | 108 | 13 |
| 2022-11-01 | 123 | 7 |
| 2022-12-01 | 132 | 20 |

I want to create a new column called `sold` that is based on a calculation - which will be a running sum of `harvested` in a period of months (Sep-Jun). Every September, `sold` will always be 1 (or 100 in percent). The calculation for Oct 2021 will be `fruits` / (`harvested` + `harvested_Nov`) = 143 / 11 + 139.

For the rest of the months of 2021, follows the same format: `fruits` / (`harvested` + `harvested_until_Sep`) --> this will be a running sum, starting from the month you're in, and ends in Sep of the previous year.

Another example for 2022 is the calculation for Mar 2022 = `fruits` / (`harvested` + `harvested_Feb_2022` + `harvested_Jan_2022` + `harvested_Dec_2021` + `harvested_Nov_2021` + `harvested_Oct_2021` + `harvested_Sep_2021`) = 123 / (5+12+10+9+14+11+139).

The table should look like this:

| month_rep | fruits | harvested | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 | 139 | 139 | 1 |
| 2021-10-01 | 143 | 11 | 0.95 |
| 2021-11-01 | 152 | 14 | 0.93 |
| 2021-12-01 | 112 | 9 | 0.65 |
| 2022-01-01 | 133 | 10 | .. |
| 2022-02-01 | 145 | 12 | .. |
| 2022-03-01 | 123 | 5 | .. |
| 2022-04-01 | 111 | 4 | .. |
| 2022-05-01 | 164 | 9 | .. |
| 2022-06-01 | 135 | 12 | .. |
| 2022-07-01 | 124 | 14 | null |
| 2022-08-01 | 144 | 18 | null |
| 2022-09-01 | 111 | 111 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 | 108 | 13 | 0.87 |
| 2022-11-01 | 123 | 7 | 0.94 |
| 2022-12-01 | 132 | 20 | .. |

I tried this:

```
select 
    month_rep,
    fruits,
    harvested,
    case when extract(month from "month_rep") in (7, 8) then null
         when extract(month from "month_rep") = 9 then 1
        else ROUND(fruits / sum(harvested) over (order by month_rep), 2) end sold
from my_table
```

This works well, but only when I have data before the 2022 September. I want Jul and Aug to have null `sold` - which works. After Aug, Sep 2022 should be a new period where `sold` is 1. After that, Oct 2022 will be calculated as `fruits` / (`harvested` + `harvested_Sep_2022`) - where we start a new period for the 2nd period Sep 2022 - Jun 2023.

Is there a way to group these "periods" and have the running sum over that? I might need to find a way to group the period and take partition by from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the date by 8 months, so that Sep-Jun moves to Jan-Sep. Then you can partition by year:

```
SELECT *
     , CASE extract(month FROM month_rep)
         WHEN 7 THEN NULL
         WHEN 8 THEN NULL
         WHEN 9 THEN 1
         ELSE round(fruits::numeric / sum(harvested) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('year', month_rep - interval '8 mon') ORDER BY month_rep), 2)
       END AS sold
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY month_rep;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=cfb7a2b2522d665d3223041b308ca974)*

Produces your desired result exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up creating a new table to be used for the partition.